# Any risk on viewing the content of a RAR file without extracting it?

Tags: compression

lets say I have a rar file that has a bunch of images inside. Is there any risk of opening the image inside the rar without extracting the entire file?

Comment: What do you mean by opening the image inside the rar? If you want to "preview" or whatever, it will require decompressing the file, and usually it saves the file to your temporary directory to open it with your default image viewer.

Answer (score 1):

There is a flaw in WinRaR that has only recently been discovered, (CVE-2021-35052).

Accessing any content within a compressed structure requires decompressing (or opening) the structure, even if you are only looking at a single file.

In principle, barring exploits like this, it ***should*** be safe, but it turns out it may not be in this case.

There is an update patch available for Winrar, there are other Rar programs, but there is never a guarantee.